# Openlayers.Bounds().transform() not doing transform

Tags: openlayers, proj4js

**Solved**.  See http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Openlayers-Bounds-transform-not-doing-transform-td3912787.html .

I am trying to do a coordinate transform of bounds in Openlayers, and have tried the following, which, for both console.log() statements, gives me the same bounds in both cases (but I expect the second statement to give me bounds in EPGS:4326):

http://pastebin.com/ADRwjLAy

In both console.log() statements, I get the following object (c&p from Chrome javascript debugger):

```
Class
bottom: 4816289.746171
centerLonLat: null
left: 189775.37995
right: 761662.354535
top: 5472414.143295
__proto__: Object
```

I read the documentation for proj4js with openlayers at trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/Documentation/Dev/proj4js , and it tells me:

> OpenLayers integrates with Proj4js if the library is available. This will make using it a bit easier. Having it in the same folder as OpenLayers.js will make it available.

Which I did via a symlink:

```
matt@xxxxxxxx:/var/www/xxxxx$ ll /var/www/OpenLayers-2.10/
total 1008
drwxr-xr-x 13 matt matt   4096 Nov  1 01:49 .
drwxrwxrwx 30 root root   4096 Nov  1 01:43 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 matt matt 945828 Sep  9  2010 OpenLayers.js
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 matt matt     31 Nov  1 01:49 proj4js.js -> /var/www/proj4js/lib/proj4js.js
...
```

Can someone help me diagnose what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Well the main problem is that your page doesn't load `proj4js.js` at all. You are presumably assuming that OpenLayers will load it automatically, but it doesn't, so you need to load it yourself.

As OpenLayers doesn't have `EPSG:26915` support built in it needs proj4js in order to do the transform you want.

A second issue is that you way want to define `EPSG:26915` explicitly by adding a line to your javascript that looks like this:

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:26915"] = "+proj=utm +zone=15 +ellps=GRS80 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs";
```

Without that I think proj4js should try and load the definition from `spatialreference.org` but that didn't seem to be working for me when I tried it.

Comment: Thanks for your help TomH, You are right, I was assuming from the documentation that placing it in the Openlayers directory meant that Openlayers would automatically load it.  I have now changed it to point to proj4js.js in its own unzipped directory (as it needed the whole directory of scripts, I thought it was self-contained).  I made the change you suggested, but have the same result of getting an identical (untransformed) object after the transform.  Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/9PaBwLDx

Comment: Well all I can say is that it works for me - see my test page at http://maps.compton.nu/project.html to see what I mean. That is using OpenLayers 2.11 but I don't think that should make any difference.